# Xamarin.Forms and Triggers: hire an action during a limited time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, triggers, datatrigger

I've developed a **Xamarin.Forms app** that can play an audio stream source.

For this, I've display a small "bar" at the bottom of the screen. This bar contains:

- a **"play"/"stop"** `Button`
- a `Label` with the name of the **current title**
- a "close" `Button`

I would like to display an **error message instead of the current title** during a **short time**, when an error occurs (like no internet access or if the URL is unreachable), with a **small animation/transition** between the 2 kinds of `Labels`.

For this, I have a `HasError` property in the **ViewModel**:

```
bool hasError = false;
public bool HasError
{
    get { return hasError; }
    set { SetProperty(ref hasError, value); }
}
```

I would like to manage this through `Triggers`.

I could do something like this:

```
<Label x:Name="RadioName"
        Text="{Binding CurrentTitle}" 
        Style="{StaticResource RadioLabelStyle}"
        Grid.Column="1">
    <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="false" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="true" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
<Label x:Name="RadioError"
        Text="{x:Static strings:Strings.RadioErrorAccessMessage}"
        Style="{StaticResource ErrorRadioLabelStyle}"
        Grid.Column="1">
    <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="false" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="true" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

This works fine, but in this case, I don't have any time limitation or any transition/animation.

***Is it possible to add time limitation and transition/animation?***

Comment: Any update for this case?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT i believe my solution answers the original question and more, but unfourounately the OP keeps changing the questions terms/conditions, I will try to take a look later, could you confirm if it working ?

Comment: The given solution works well for the `ConnectionStatus` issue. However it doesn't seem the better way to manage others errors that are managed in the VM (like URL unreachable), as that requires to refer to some properties of VM in the code-behind of the View... So I finally used a ShowError property in the VM that fires the display of the error, without using `Triggers` longer.

Answer (score 1):

1. xaml part use [MultiTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers), here an example with a `Label`

```
    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="Online" FontSize="25">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ConnectionStatus}" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Error Connection Lost"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
         </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
```

- Define `ConnectionStatus` property

```
private bool _ConnectionStatus = true;

        public bool ConnectionStatus
        {
            get => _ConnectionStatus;
            set => SetProperty(ref _ConnectionStatus, value); //raise InotifyPropertyChanged
        }
```

Note: I didn't include the Inotifyproperty event code (lot of answers here about it)

2. Logic part: For lost connection you can use [ConnectivityChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) event from Xamarin essentials:

- Subscribe to the event

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
}
```

- UnSubscribe from the event

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
}
```

- Handle the event: Will display the error message for 5 seconds after connection lost.

```
async void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var access = e.NetworkAccess;
    if (access != NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
        VM.ConnectionStatus = false;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        VM.ConnectionStatus = true;
    }
}
```

#### Note

`VM` is a a reference to your View Model where `ConnectionStatus` should be defined, also don't forget to properly set your page `BindingContext`.

If you don't want to use View Model, no issue simply define `ConnectionStatus` property (and handle `INotifyPropertyChanged`) in your code behind instead of the view model. In that case `ConnectionStatus = false;` and `BindingContext = this;.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses his question.  He's asking how to put a time limit on a UI element displayed via a trigger

Comment: @Jason Thanks for pointing out, I have updated my answer

Comment: Hi @Cfun thanks for your suggestion. So you think I need to call the ViewModel from the View  (like you do with `VM.ConnectionStatus = false`) to achieve this? I would like to avoid this, but I may have no choice.

Comment: You can absolutely avoid it, simply define `ConnectionStatus` property (and handle INotifyPropertyChanged) in your code behind instead of vm. That case `ConnectionStatus = false;` don't forget to set `BindingContext = this;` after `InitializeComponent`

Comment: Yes sure, but in this case I have logical part in the code-behind... Is it possible to use a ViewModel's property instead of the `Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged` event? I've created a "common" property for the errors (no internet access or other issues): so I would like to bind the trigger to this property. Do I need to create an event in the ViewModel for this?

Comment: if I understood right you already have a defiend method in your vm and want to call it when even happened ? (I am a bit confused, you said you don't want to use vm and now you want to use vm)

Comment: Yes sorry, it seems easier to use the ViewModel as I manage several kinds of errors. So in my ViewModel, I have a boolean property `HasError` that is set to `True`in case of issues (no internet access, wrong url, ...). I would like to hide the current title, and display the error message during 3 seconds when this property is set to `True`.

Comment: You refer to `Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged` from Xamarin Essentials, whereas I wand to refer to another ViewModel's property: `HasError`

Comment: `HasError` was not included in the question, I don't know how it is defined (being set/updated) you can probably bind it in xaml instead of ConnectionStatus and set it to true when connection lost

Comment: You're right @Cfun. I've added some details to my original post. I think I could adapt your solution by adding an `EventHandler` related to the `HasError` property in my ViewModel.

Comment: But shouldn't it be possible to bind the `Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged` directly to the trigger? Cause in your solution, the View update a property of the ViewModel, whereas I would like that the VM hires the switch of the `Labels` in the View, that could be done programatically.